# 2 questions about distro and map

Tags: simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1、can I connect my laptop(running Hydro) to the robot(running Indigo)?

2、How can I generate a map of the environment(this map I can store it and use it on RVIZ to do the simulation work)?I want to compare the real condition with the simulation condition.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261577/2-questions-about-distro-and-map/) by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Yes you can communicate with the ROS Topics independent from the ROS Version
2. Is likely more difficult to answer because I have no Idea about your robot, environment and map.
   But the problem you want do solve is commonly named SLAM (Simultaneous Localization and Mapping). There are two most popular SLAM packages in ROS:

---

1. [GMapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping)
2. [Hector SLAM](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam)

Both of them need a laserscan and GMapping also a Odometry (in form of a transformation from odom to base_link)

You can save and load the created map with the [Map Server package](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server).

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-05-15**:
Thank you!